What does the non-reusable category on OSI mean?
https://opensource.org/licenses can list their licenses by category.
There is one category: NON-REUSABLE that, to me, sounds a bit off for OSI licenses.
What does this category categorize for the OSI licenses falling under it?
What exactly is non-reusable here?

In the OSI's Proliferation Report, it defines "non-reusable" licenses:

Licenses in this group are specific to their authors and
cannot be reused by others. Many, but not all, of these licenses
fall into the category of vanity licenses.

The same definition is also provided on the index of licenses by category.

Exactly.  Many of these licenses embed specific organization names, repositories, reporting processes, or library names in a way that's not easily templateable.  These licenses are listed to show that they are, in fact, open source, but you shouldn't copy these licenses to use with your unrelated project.
